# Ranking Rows based on similarities between column values C# or SQL

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq, grouping

I have a table with multiple rows split by Time Series.

```
ReportId    Trade   PriceIndex  PriceDate   Price   Row_Number
   1             t  PriceIndexA 1-Jan-12    0          1
   1             t  PriceIndexB 16-Jan-12   1          2
   1             t  PriceIndexB 18-Feb-12   2          3
   1             t  PriceIndexB 20-Mar-12   3          4
   2             t  PriceIndexA 2-Jan-12    0          5
   2             t  PriceIndexB 16-Jan-12   1          6
   2             t  PriceIndexB 18-Feb-12   3          7
   2             t  PriceIndexB 20-Mar-12   4          8
```

I want to be able to group each row from `ReportID` 1 to `ReportId` 2
as you can see,  Report Id is unique in one day and trade is common but the values in `PriceIndex` , `PriceDate` and `Price` keeps moving from one day to another day.

In the above example, i am expecting the groups to be as follows

- Row 1 maps to Row 5
- Row 2 maps to Row 6
- Row 3 maps to Row 7
- Row 4 maps to Row 8..

Any pointers on how to solve this issue?

Comment: `row_number() over (partition by reportID order by  PriceDate, Price) as seq` Does it help?

Comment: thanks kiril, i did think about that but then day one it can be such that the pricedate is the most common, day 2 it can be prices which is the most common..so the query has to dynamically evolve.

Comment: then what if you create 2 sequences: 1 for `priceDate` and 1 for `Price`. Afterwards, compare these 2 and get only the value that you need

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding the question. Could you elaborate more on how you want to group?